# Where do OpenShift questions belong to?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

[OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com) is a cloud by Red Hat.

It has certain API and specific environment, which would nominate it to StackOverflow.

But mostly it would be about administration, which I guess belongs to serverfault.

Correct? Or is it rather case-by-case?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the question.

If your question is primarily about writing code that uses the APIs, then you're looking for feedback from developers, and you should post it on Stack Overflow.

On the other hand, if it's about managing VMs/services/cloud infrastructure, you're more likely to be looking for help from fellow system administrators. In that case, your question should be posted on Server Fault.

"Scripting"-type questions, say automation tasks related to service deployment, aren't always clear-cut. In that case, look at which hat you're wearing: if you've got your coder hat on, go for Stack Overflow. If you've got your sysadmin's cap and toolbelt, head over to Server Fault.

In any case, as long as your question is well written, don't worry too much about it for borderline questions. A good question will be migrated to the right site if people think you'll be better served somewhere else.